# ajax call with object list

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

i have the following scripting:

```
obj = [];
            obj = [{ AllocationStatus: false,
                BRId: 2,
                BRName: "rifat",
                SupervisorId: 19,
                SupervisorName: "Ashraful"
            }];
            console.log(obj);
            var data2send = JSON.stringify(obj);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../WebService1.asmx/allocatebr",
                data: "{'brlist':'" + data2send + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error f');
                }
            });
```

in web service i have the following code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string allocatebr(List<Allocation> brlist)
    {
        //foreach(Allocation br in brlist){

        //}

        return "success";

    }

public class Allocation
    {
        public int SupervisorId { get; set; }
        public string SupervisorName { get; set; }
        public int BRId { get; set; }
        public string BRName { get; set; }
        public bool AllocationStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

but i get the error:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) .what's wrong with my code?i want to pass object list to the method.how to do it?Anyone helps me is greatly appreciated.
n.b.i got the obj array

```
`$('.chkgrip').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        var x = $(this).closest('tr').data('row');
                        obj.push(x);
                    }
            });`
```

Comment: For issues like this where you're not really sure if the problem lies on the client side or server side, you'd do well use something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to read the HTTP request that you're making and see if the body of your request is as you had hoped.
In your case it appears that the client side code works just fine and the body of the request contains the json blob as you'd expect.
You need to find out what the internal server error is before we can really help you

Comment: plz sugest some tutorial.i can't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following works for me:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 [WebMethod]
    public static string allocatebr(string brlist)
    {

        List<Allocationbr> brs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Allocationbr>>(brlist);
        foreach (Allocationbr b in brs)
        {
            x......
        }
        return x.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `[WebMethod]` attribute will produce a SOAP (XML) based web service. That cannot be called using an URL, the way how you tried it. To do it you need a rest service.

I would recommend [Asp.Net Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx).

Comment: why not?is it possible without wcf?plz help me out.